# Retaining uiwebview when changing tab bar view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar view controller with two tab views, one blank and one with a uiwebview. How can I retain the loaded page if I change between the two tab views? So it won't get reloaded again until I leave the tab bar controller?

Thanks

Comment: in view did load try if (!_webView) {
        _webView=[[UIWebView alloc] init]; [_webView loadRequest:Your_Request];
    }

Comment: thanks it worked:) but I feel the app to be pretty laggy. does it ever unload then?

Comment: with ARC , you dont need to be worried anymore about unload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in view did load try

```
if (!_webView)
 { 
   _webView=[[UIWebView alloc] init]; 
   [_webView loadRequest:Your_Request]; 
}
```